# Quasi Poisson model quasi-likelihood

Tags: overdispersion, quasi-likelihood

Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_function) gives this as the general definition of  quasi-(log)-likelihood:
$$ Q(\mu,y)= \int _{y}^{\mu} \frac{y-t}{\sigma^2 V(t)} dt$$ 
In the case of quasi poisson regression, what are $\sigma^2$ and $V$?
I know that we assume the relationship of the mean and the variance to be linear, so I guess $V(t)=\phi t $, where $\phi$ is the over dispersion parameter.
Am I correct?